# A-Frame a-animation vs kframe animation__id components behave differently

Tags: animation, components, aframe

Code: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/aframe-nyc?path=ballani.html:17:0

Demo: https://aframe-nyc.glitch.me/ballani.html

Description:
I am putting two bouncing balls next to each other Red (left) *using kframe animation* and Green (right) *using the soon deprecating a-animation component*

Problem:
Green switches to yellow on the way up, which is the intended behavior.
Red **should** switch to blue on the way up, but doesn't, what is wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It works if I use a hash color. I'll look into why a keyword color name doesn't work.

```
animation__switch="property: material.color; from: #F00; to: #0F0; dur: 1000; delay: 0; dir: alternate; easing: linear; loop: true; autoplay: true"
```

Note you can get more performant animations this way:

```
animation__switch="property: components.material.material.color; type: color; from: #F00; to: #0F0; dur: 1000; delay: 0; dir: alternate; easing: linear; loop: true; autoplay: true"
```

Comment: the issue happens when I combine delay and duration. I want the color switch to happen instantly (dur:0) after the ball drops (delay:1000) - it looks like delay only triggers once and does not loop.